# Incrementing variable passed into my javascript recursive calls refusing to update

Tags: javascript, recursion, depth-first-search

I'm trying to solve leetcode 112.Path Sum. I pass in currSum as 0 initially and want to increment currSum value by adding previous currSum value to current root.val - but currSum is not increasing, see code below:

```
var hasPathSum = function(root, targetSum) {
    var result = helper(root, targetSum, 0);
    return result;
};

function helper(root, targetSum, currSum){
    if(root === null) return false;

    currSum = currSum + root.val;
    console.log(currSum);

    if(root.left === null && root.right === null && currSum === targetSum){
        return true;
    }

    return hasPathSum(root.left, targetSum, currSum) || hasPathSum(root.right, targetSum, currSum);
}

can someone please point me to what i am doing wrongly. Thanks in advance.
```

See link to the problem statement here https://leetcode.com/problems/path-sum/

What i expect currSum to be is:
5
9
20
27
22
...

but what i get is:
5
4
11
7
2
8
13
4
1

Observe that it is just printing back the current root.val at each recursive call.

Comment: could you repost the problem statement here?

Comment: @gog I have posted the link to the problem statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you call this function

```
var hasPathSum = function(root, targetSum) {
    var result = helper(root, targetSum, 0);
```

It will call helper with last parameter as zero and it only accepts two parameters - `root` and `targetSum`

Therefore when you call at the end of function

```
hasPathSum(root.left, targetSum, currSum)
```

The `currSum` is not used in any way, it is just lost

I have not checked the logic itself, but to keep the `currSum` value you need to use it in this way:

```
return helper(root.left, targetSum, currSum) || helper(root.right, targetSum, currSum);
```

Comment: What is the best way to achieve my purpose?

Comment: Reading through your comment again i finally realized that i was making the recursive call with hasPathSum instead of with my helper function. Let's just say sometimes my head is full. Probably would have been wondering for hours if i did not post this here. Thanks all the same.